# Traits\SimpleTree getAllChildren method getting duplicate children in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I am using SimpleTree of octobercms, i am trying to get all nested childrens of perticular category with getAllChildren() method, below is my code.

```
$categories = Category::find($id)->getAllChildren();
return $categories;
```

This is showing all children categories but every children got reapeted. Please visit link to view my output in json format
https://jsonblob.com/bbb23b15-ec0d-11e8-b66c-8512ae73d6e1

Please help i have tried all method related to children.

Comment: I guess something is not correct in code. can you share `Category Model` code. `and did you add that parent children relations`. also it would be nice if you can `share field details` as well :)

Comment: Without knowing the code of Model Bindings , we can't figure out the issue. Your provided JSON link cant help us to solve the issue as its already a final output. So it would be great if you provide that chunk of code in order to get the things going.

Comment: Thanks you guys for comments, i have solved this issue.